# Login users from other sites in my laravel app with their account

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a laravel 7 website that's mainly used as a membership program for some companies.

A new feature demands that users from those companies may login in my site with their account (account of my site) through a request generated on their company side.

Each app has its own DB. In my DB I keep track from which app each user is.

What would be a secure approach to accomplish this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement an API using either Laravel Passport or Laravel Sanctum for authentication, depending on your use-case/preference.

Here are a couple of boilerplate projects that you can take a look at for reference:

- Passport: https://github.com/pktharindu/nuxt-laravel-passport-example
- Sanctum: https://github.com/pktharindu/laravel-api-boilerplate

You'll of course need to do some customizations to keep track of where the user is coming from.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look on them!